# Disable navigation during powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint

For a school project we have develop a plugin for powerpoint. The problem is that we want, on some slides, to show a timer during the presentation and disable the navigation until the timer is finished. I really don't have a clue about how to do it and even if it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply navigation links on every slide rather than allowing the user to navigate with the usual keyboard controls, AND set the presentation to display in KIOSK mode, then you could have your timer slide with no navigation controls appear, then once the timer times out, your code advances to the next slide, which is a duplicate of the one with the timer BUT it has navigation controls, so the user can continue with the presentation.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know KIOSK mode so i will search about this and try this solution